# Checkbox value in Action class Struts 2

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, checkbox, struts2

I want to access checkbox value in the action class which I am setting in javascript

```jsp
<s:checkbox key="mstDesignations.isActive" id="isActive"></s:checkbox>


<button type="button" class="submitBtn" onclick="adddesignation()"></button>
```

**javascript:**

```javascript
function adddesignation() {    
    if(document.designationForm.isActive.checked==true){
      document.designationForm.isActive.fieldValue=1;               
    }
    else if( document.designationForm.isActive.checked==false)
    {
      document.designationForm.isActive.fieldValue=2;
    }
    alert(document.designationForm.isActive.fieldValue);
    document.designationForm.submit();
}
```

When I try to access it in action class like below I get null

```java
public MDesig mstDesignations=new MDesig();

System.out.println("Is Active value:::" +mstDesignations.getIsActive());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change javascript to assign the value of the field by name. Assumed `designationForm` is the form name and `mstDesignations.isActive` is the field name.

```
this.designationForm['mstDesignations.isActive'].value=1;
```